# Trying to understand the derivation of magnetic field around a current loop.

Tags: calculus

I'm reading *Edward M. Purcell*'s *Electricity and Magnetism*.

I'm having trouble in conceiving his derivation:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

The vector potential is $$\mathbf A(0,y_1,z_1)= \frac{\mu_0I}{4\pi}\int \frac{\mathrm d\mathbf l_2}{r_{12}}\;.$$

He then wrote about the

> variation in the denominator $r_{12}$ as we go round the loop. If $P_1$ is far away, the **first-order variation** in $r_{12}$ depends only on the coordinate $y_2$ of the segment $\mathrm d\mathbf l_2$ and not on $x_2\;.$ Thus, neglecting quantities proportional to $\left(\frac{x_2}{r_{12}}\right)^2$, we may treat $r_{12}$ and $r'_{12}$ as equal. We have $$r_{12}= r_1 - y_2\sin\theta$$  [...]

Then he says,

> Without spoiling our **first-order approximation** , we can write $$\frac{1}{r_{12}}\approx \frac{1}{r_1}\left(1+\frac{y_2\sin\theta}{r_1}\right)$$

Can anyone tell me, what Purcell meant by **first-order approximation**? Why does the variation of $r_{12}$ around the loop not depend on $x_{12}\;?$ I'm not getting that. Also, how did he write $\frac{1}{r_{12}}\approx \frac{1}{r_1}\left(1+\frac{y_2\sin\theta}{r_1}\right)\;?$

Also, he says that '$\int \mathrm d x_2$ around the loop vanishes'. Why is it so?

Please explain the subtleties I'm facing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do it in the plane, which captures everything.  Point C at $(x_1,0)$ is the observation point and point D, with coordinates $(x_2,y_2)$ is the source point.  $a$ is $r_{12}$.  My figure has the axes reversed, so the first order variation in $r_{12}$ comes from $x_2$, not $y_2$.  $r_{12}=\sqrt{(x_1-x_2)^2+y_2^2}=x_1\sqrt{(1-\frac{x_2}{x_1})^2+(\frac{y_2}{x_1})^2}$  When we expand the square root in a Taylor series, we get $x_1\sqrt{(1-\frac{x_2}{x_1})^2+(\frac{y_2}{x_1})^2}\approx x_1(1-\frac {x_2}{2x_1}+\frac 12(\frac{y_2}{x_1})^2)$ and we can see the change depends linearly on $\frac {x_2}{x_1}$ and quadratically on $\frac{y_2}{x_1}$.  This is what is meant by first and second order.  To the extent the loop is small compared to $x_1$, the second order term will be very small.
[image]